# How to obtain property name and types (by reflexion or better) of a linq result anonymous type

Tags: linq, properties, introspection

I need to obtain property names and types of a linq result (by reflection or better)...
I say better because I think linq should have a structure in every query with this info!!!

for example

I have a linq query like:

dim query1 = from e0 in clients select new { e0.id, e0.name }

I pass query1 as a parameter to a function, then I need to know how much properties there are in query1, the property names and the property types...

Thx, ZEE ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Type memberType = query1.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
foreach (var a in query1)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in memberType.GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(a, null));
    }
}
```

actually I will store the `PropertyInfo`s in a `List<PropertyInfo>` and in the inner foreach, use the stored properties. But the above code is the simplest to understand.

Comment: Hi Alireza... this is not working... the inner cycle never gets executed. Any sugestions?

Comment: var q0 = from e0 in a0
 select new 
  { id = e0, 
  nome = "Client#"+e0, 
  data = e0 * e0 ,  
  flag = e0 % 2
  };

// 'q0.Dump();

Type memberType = q0.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
foreach (var a in q0)
{
 Console.WriteLine( "this is executed OK!" );
 foreach (PropertyInfo pi in memberType.GetProperties())
 {
  Console.WriteLine("this will not execute!");
  Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(a, null));
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be passing query results typed as a sequence of instances of an anonymous type to another method. If you're doing this, you should make a concrete class for the query results.

You can use reflection to tear out the properties from `query1` as follows. `query1` will implement `IEnumerable<T>` for some unique type `T`. Once you have this type, you can call

```
type.GetProperties()
```

to get an enumeration of the anonymous type member names.

Comment: Sorry mate,,, I've already been there... and I really need to pass anonymous types as a computation to another functions (Microsoft says that only can´t be done between assemblies, so no problems in the same assembly), Thx anyway... ZEE